# Performance of XML file and LayoutInflater vs Creating view from code

Tags: android, performance, view, layout-inflater

I am needing to dynamically change the child views (remove them then add different ones) within a LinearLayout in my app.
I can create all the views via code or I could use LayoutInflater and then just set the fields that I need to change.

Is there a difference in speed and RAM usage between the two?

Any of the layouts I add will have a maximum of 10 views, usually less than 5. And I'm not concerned about complexity of coding, just the performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference in speed and RAM usage between the two?

Not significantly. At the level of a microbenchmark, inflating layouts is certainly slower than doing it by hand. However, you are not trying to do this hundreds of times a second (I hope), and so the speed difference is negligible.

Of course, even faster would be to not "remove them then add different ones", but to change visibility of already-created widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why adding view by code wouldn't be better in performance under one condition. That you implement what array adaptor really do.

Which is, only creating two or three view at the beginning. The visible views only. Then, start moving them and change info. Displayed on "scrolling". Otherwise adapter is better because it does not create all the graphics for all items at a time.